# Cannot load webpage using domain name, but I can load it using IP address

Tags: networking, dns, webserver, domain, cloudflare

HI! I have just set up a web server on aws ubuntu using apache2. I can load the page using my IP address but not my domain name. I have tried nslook up and it found my IP address using the domain name. Using cloudflare and I have reconfigured all and yet is still not working. Any thoughts? (I have enable port 443, 80 and 22 on was security rules and I can access the page and server using ssh).
Best!!

Comment: Please post your Apache config. Did you add the domain for the `ServerName` option? Look up the [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Oh I haven't configured that yet! Thanks and may I know which file should I edit?

Comment: Usually a conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory. The [tutorial on ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/web-servers-apache) would be a good starting point for understanding how to configure the server.